# Append many classes to style in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that allows to add style with class to head section:

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .redbold{ color:#f00; font-weight:bold;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

If I call this code elsewhere, a new style section is created each time and it looks like this :

```
<style type="text/css"> .redbold{ color:#f00; font-weight:bold;} </style>
<style type="text/css"> .newclass{ color:black;} </style>
```

Is this possible to add a new class many times to the style section and do not create new ones each time? Thanks for help

Comment: Put an `id` on the style block and then access it.  `<style id="mystyles">...</style>`   and then `$('#mystyles').append(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Put an id on the style block:

```
<style id="mystyles">...</style>
```

then use jQuery to access it:

```
$('#mystyles').append(...);
```

Now you can access it as often as you like!